# How to access Group Collection as key value pair in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, collections

How to access Group Collection as key value pair. I need to access group specific element of select or provided group . Please see code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <fx:XMLList id="defaultColumns">
        <ROW>
            <NAME>DESCRIPTION_</NAME>
            <COLUMN_CAPTION>Description</COLUMN_CAPTION>
            <COLUMN_WIDTH>40</COLUMN_WIDTH>
            <GROUP_DESCRIPTION>0. General</GROUP_DESCRIPTION>
            <OPTIONS/>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <NAME>@action</NAME>
            <COLUMN_CAPTION>Action</COLUMN_CAPTION>
            <COLUMN_WIDTH>20</COLUMN_WIDTH>
            <GROUP_DESCRIPTION>0. General</GROUP_DESCRIPTION>
            <OPTIONS/>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <NAME>@err</NAME>
            <COLUMN_CAPTION>Error</COLUMN_CAPTION>
            <COLUMN_WIDTH>5</COLUMN_WIDTH>
            <GROUP_DESCRIPTION>0. General</GROUP_DESCRIPTION>
            <Color>#FF0000</Color>      
            <OPTIONS/>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <NAME>@sql</NAME>
            <COLUMN_CAPTION>Sql</COLUMN_CAPTION>
            <COLUMN_WIDTH>1</COLUMN_WIDTH>
            <GROUP_DESCRIPTION>0. General</GROUP_DESCRIPTION>
            <OPTIONS/>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <NAME>DESCRIPTION_</NAME>
            <COLUMN_CAPTION>Description</COLUMN_CAPTION>
            <COLUMN_WIDTH>40</COLUMN_WIDTH>
            <GROUP_DESCRIPTION>0. General2</GROUP_DESCRIPTION>
            <OPTIONS/>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <NAME>@action</NAME>
            <COLUMN_CAPTION>Action</COLUMN_CAPTION>
            <COLUMN_WIDTH>20</COLUMN_WIDTH>
            <GROUP_DESCRIPTION>0. General2</GROUP_DESCRIPTION>
            <OPTIONS/>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <NAME>@err</NAME>
            <COLUMN_CAPTION>Error</COLUMN_CAPTION>
            <COLUMN_WIDTH>5</COLUMN_WIDTH>
            <GROUP_DESCRIPTION>0. General2</GROUP_DESCRIPTION>
            <Color>#FF0000</Color>      
            <OPTIONS/>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <NAME>@sql</NAME>
            <COLUMN_CAPTION>Sql</COLUMN_CAPTION>
            <COLUMN_WIDTH>1</COLUMN_WIDTH>
            <GROUP_DESCRIPTION>0. General2</GROUP_DESCRIPTION>
            <OPTIONS/>
        </ROW>
    </fx:XMLList>
    <mx:GroupingCollection id="colGroup" source="{defaultColumns}">
        <mx:grouping>
            <mx:Grouping>
                <mx:GroupingField name="GROUP_DESCRIPTION"  />
            </mx:Grouping>
        </mx:grouping>
    </mx:GroupingCollection>
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
   <![CDATA[
protected function groupTabs_changeHandler(event:IndexChangedEvent):void
{
        var xmlList:XMLList=XMLList(colGroup.getRoot()[groupTabs.selectedChild.label]);
                Alert.show(xmlList.toXMLString());
}
 ]]>
 </fx:Script>
  <mx:TabNavigator id="groupTabs" borderStyle="solid" width="100%" initialize="{colGroup.refresh()}" change="groupTabs_changeHandler(event)">
   <mx:Repeater dataProvider="{colGroup.getRoot()}" id="t">
     <mx:VBox  label="{t.currentItem.GroupLabel.toString()}" width="100%"></mx:VBox>
  </mx:Repeater>
  </mx:TabNavigator>    
 </s:Application>
```

I want to access group specific xmllist here any possibilty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read [Displaying grouped data](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_08.html) it shows how to manipulate group data
also read [Grouping](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/Grouping.html) object "a collection of grouped data"

*The Grouping class defines the fields in the data provider of the AdvancedDataGrid control used to group data*

In pasted code **t.currentItem** contains group specific collection under **Repeater** control

Hopes that helps